# How to get Map.values as a Set rather than a Collection?

Tags: java, dictionary, collections

I have a map `Map<String, SomeType>` where every instance of `SomeType` is added by name like `map.put(object.getName(), object)`. In the end, there are no duplicates in `map.values()`.

Now, I want a `Set<SomeType>` from this map without making a copy like `new HashSet<>(map.values())`.

Is this possible, preferential only with the standard library?

Comment: It isn't a Set. You'll have to make a copy. Or just use Collection, knowing there are no duplicates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already know how to do it with `new HashSet<>(map.values())`. You can't get a Set of the values directly, since the values can contain duplicates. Even if in your specific Map there are no duplicate values, in a general Map there can be duplicate values.

You can do something with Java 8 Streams, but it has no advantage over instantiating the Set explicitly.

```
Set<SomeType> values = map.values().stream().collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 2):

Without a `Collection` wrapper it is not possible.

Just because in your case there are no duplications, that does not mean they cannot be.

Java Collections API allow you to put duplicate values in the `Map`, so the contract has to return `Collection` and not `Set`.

Answer (score 2):

It would be a simple matter to create a `Set` view of any `Collection`.

```
public final class SetView<E> extends AbstractSet<E> {

    private final Collection<? extends E> collection;

    private SetView(Collection<? extends E> collection) {
        this.collection = collection;
    }

    public static <E> SetView<E> of(Collection<? extends E> collection) {
        return new SetView<>(collection);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object e) {
        return collection.contains(e);
    }

    // rest omitted.
}
```

With this, you could then write `Set<E> set = SetView.of(map.values());` and all changes to the `Map` would automatically be reflected in the `Set`.

The problem with this approach is that some methods would be difficult to implement without copying the `Collection`. For example, how would you write `size()`?

The most sensible way is

```
@Override
public int size() {
    return new HashSet<>(collection).size();
}
```

but this defeats the purpose of using a view rather than just copying the elements in the first place. If you know that the `Collection` will never contain duplicates, you *could* simply do

```
@Override
public int size() {
    return collection.size();
}
```

However I would advise against such an approach. A `Map` is allowed to contain duplicate values, and the possibility of adding two entries with the same value means that the contract for `Set` would be broken.

Unless you have *very* good reason for not wanting to copy the elements, I would just use `new HashSet<>(map.values())`.